# Can we prove that the section is globally 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose $X$ is an irreducible space (meaning every open nonempty subset is dense), of dimension 1 (meaning the only closed irreducible subspaces are singletons and $X$), such that points are closed in $X$. Suppose $F$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$, and $s \in F(X)$ is a global section such that $s|_{X-\{p\}} = 0$ for some point $p \in X$. Can we conclude that $s =0$ ? What I tried so far is the following: if we can prove $\{x \in X \mid s_x = 0 \in F_x\}$ is closed we're done. 
But I cannot prove it. I'm also not sure whether the result holds, but it should at least hold if $X$ is a smooth curve and $F$ is the sheaf of $1$-forms on it (I need it in this context). Could someone help me out? I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the full generality you've made is not true - consider a skyscraper sheaf located at $p$, for instance. The case you describe where $X$ is a smooth curve is true - when $X$ is smooth, $\Omega^1_X$ is locally free, which means it has no torsion. A nonzero section supported only at $p$ would be torsion, so such a section must be zero.

Comment: Thanks for the skyscraper counterexample! However, I don’t teally know what “to have torsion” or “to be torsion” means in this context so I cannot fully understand your answer. Is it by the way easy to show $\Omega_^1_X$ is locally free in this case? Thanks

Comment: A torsion section of a $\mathcal{O}_X$ module $\mathcal{F}$ is a section $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ so that there exists a function $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ so that $fs=0$. This is the sheafified version of torsion in abelian groups, or torsion in modules over rings. To show $\Omega_X^1$ is locally free for a smooth scheme is standard and should be in your text - for example, in Hartshorne, it's theorem II.8.15.